Delta in FX Options markets
In several FX options textbooks, the authors explain that put-call parity combined with the fact that FX option market makers trade options with a delta hedge included, means that it does not matter if a put or a call is traded, but rather if it is a long or short strike.
Both a put and a call will have the same delta exposures.
Does this mean that both a put and a call have positive delta, and if so, how come?

No, put has negative delta and call has positive delta.

The answer is in the question. A put with a delta hedge (by put call parity) = call. Assume delta is a close to frictionless asset and immediately tradeable, therefore a put and a delta hedge is a call and vice versa.
Therefore, it follows if a put plus delta hedge is equivalent to a call it must have exactly the same risk too.
